# Replace string in many js files

Tags: sed

I have many files(.js files), under a directory and subdirectories. I want to replace the lines which ends in ';', with the original line plus `print.f("filename" with linenumber");`. The actual filename and linenumber where it was found.

example - line ending with ';'

```
var x = 5;
```

should be replaced with

```
var x = 5;print.f("test.js with line number 16");
```

`test.js` and `16` are the filename and linenumber where `var x = 5;` was found respectively.

Edit

The test.js and 16 are samples, in the output it should be the filename and the linemunber

Answer (score 1):

If you are flexible in using `awk`:

```
awk '{printf $0} /.*\;$/{printf " print.f(\"" FILENAME " with line number " NR "\");"} {printf "\n"}' filename
```

This will add the `print.f` statement whenever the lines ends with `;`.

Unless you have GNU awk 4.1.0 or later, you will have to write the output of the command temporarily to a file and then move it back.

For GNU awk 4.1.0 and above, you can use `-i` option for inplace file editing.

```
gawk -i '{printf $0} /.*\;$/{printf " print.f(\"" FILENAME " with line number " NR "\");"} {printf "\n"}' filename
```

---

To find all `.js` files and run the above `gawk` command on them:

```
find . -type f -name "*.js" | xargs gawk -i '{printf $0} /.*\;$/{printf " print.f(\"" FILENAME " with line number " NR "\");"} {printf "\n"}'
```

Comment: Hi Jenish, Thanks. I tried the awk command, but it gave back an error saying awk: read error (Is a directory), when i gave the directory name at the top. Does it work with directory, under which there are subdirectories and files.